# PHP - PDO SQLite3 Prepared Statements

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to use prepared statements in a PHP script that accesses an SQLite3 database using PDO.

The normal version of this query works as expected:

```
$q1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruits WHERE name='apple'";
echo $db->query($q1)->fetchColumn();
```

However, my prepared statement version outputs nothing.

```
$q2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruits WHERE name='?'";
$s = $db->prepare($q2);
$s->execute("apple");
echo $s->fetchColumn();
```

What am I doing wrong?
I tried with both PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3, with the same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you don't need additional apostrophes before and after the ? and you should use an array: $s->execute(array("apple"));